# insecure permissions 0644, 0600 suggested

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to make a swap on my new micro-controller on Ubuntu 18.04, but this is happening to me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Edit] your question and show us what you did to "make a swap", and exactly which error messages were produced.

Answer (score 2):

`swap` should be accessible only by `root` (`0600`). Letting `swap` be read by group and other (`0644`) is a security hole, as it exposes the memory of swapped-out processes, which might contain decrypted passwords or other credentials.

You can repair this with `sudo chmod 0600 ...`.